# Handling CRLF, CR and LF when reading a txt file

Tags: c, newline, lf

I have a portion of C-code as below which is complied in linux gcc environment.

In my project I have to handle ALL CRLF, CR and LF when reading a txt file created from different OS.

I'm not sure if fscanf() handles all cases automatically.

Is there any other way that can handle all cases?

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data) != EOF) 
{
    printf("%d\n", data);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: All the "newlines" are white-space. And the `"%d"` format of [`scanf` (and family)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) skips leading white-space.

Comment: Furthermore, if you open a file in text-mode, then the system should translate any system-dependent line-ending into plain newline `'\n'` when reading (and the opposite translation when writing).

Comment: See [Trailing white space in a format string is a UI disaster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-difference-between-scanfd-and-scanfd)

Comment: There is no standard way to deal with the three alternative line endings. If you must deal with such data, then (a) it is easiest if each file is self-consistent and (b) you have to write the code yourself because there is no standard. If the files are self-consistent, analyze the first line of a file, and then use the knowledge to handle the line endings consistently (see POSIX [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html)). If each file can contain a mix of endings, then you have to code the test into your own line reading code. Fiddly; not hard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Opening the file in text mode is insufficient here for OP cases.

Comment: @chux But both carriage-return and newline (`'\r'` and `'\n'`) are, even on their own and without translation, still white-space (as reported by [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)), which means it will still be skipped over with the code in the question. Unless the OP needs to actually count the spaces or the number of lines, and only reads integers as shown, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes in the narrow case of `fscanf(fp, "%d", ...`, there is little issue and file mode, being text of binary is not important.  In the general case of `fscanf(fp, some_format, ...`, text mode is insufficient alone to handle OP's goal.

Answer (score 1):

> to handle ALL CRLF, CR and LF when reading a txt file created from different OS.
>
> I'm not sure if `fscanf()` handles all cases automatically.

Some usage of `fscanf()` will work fine like `fscanf(fp, "%d", &data)`, but not all.

A simple alternative is to read *lines* of input with your own `my_fgets()`, and then call `sscanf()`.

```
char my_fgets(char *s, size_t sz, FILE *fp) {
  if (sz < 1) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char *org = s;
  bool no_input = true;
  int ch = 0;

  while (--sz > 0 && (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { 
    no_input = false; 
    if (ch == '\r') {
      int ch2 = fgetc(fp);
      if (ch2 != '\n') ungetc(ch2, fp);
      break;
    }
    if (ch == '\n') {
      break;
    }
    *s++ = ch;
  }
  *s = '\0';
  if ((ch == EOF) && (no_input || !feof(fp))) return NULL;
  return org;
} 

my_fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);
sscanf(buffer, ...);
```

This will handle most situations should the file be open in binary or text mode.

---

Relying on text mode and system-dependent line-ending translation is insufficient as code needs to handle at least 3 cases, some of which might not correspond to the expected system-dependent line-ending.

Comment: This is more or less the code used by Kernighan and Pike in [The Practice of Programming](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/tpop.webpage/) (1999).  It is about the best you can do.   I happened to be re-reading it last night, and it occurs to me that if you were doing terminal input on a system where `\r` is the line ending, then the `fgetc(fp)` to read an extra character (to see if it is a newline) would hang waiting for the next line. Similarly with piped data; if the far end of the pipe sends lines that end `\r`, the code would jam waiting for another character to see whether it's a newline.

Comment: This isn't knocking what you've shown; it is (as I said) about the best that can be done (without any extra knowledge about the expected line endings).  And the problem is mostly more theoretical than practical.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fortunately OP implies `fp` is a file and not `stdin`, yet your blocking point is valid in general.

Comment: I wonder if you can treat `'\r'` as a line ending always, without testing the next character, and somehow record that you ended a line with CR and if the first character of the next line is LF (NL), omit it from the new line of input?  That would avoid the blocking; it probably requires a structure wrapped around a file stream to keep the context.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll ponder that idea

Comment: This is me thinking out loud (sorry you're being subjected to the noise).  :D